# How to Duplicate an array list in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, duplication

I have an array list that stores objects called Movie. The objects contain variables such as name , date released ,genre etc.. Is there a way to duplicate the array so I can sort it one by one keep the original data unchanged. I will be displaying the data in text areas.

Comment: I think you can use `clone` to duplicate arraylist and create a new with the same data inside it, by this way you will be able to save the memory and a good solution without compromising performance.

Comment: You want to duplicate `ArrayList` or array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
List<Movie> newList = new ArrayList<>(existingList);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a copy of the old `ArrayList` with:

```
List<Movie> newList = new ArrayList<Movie>(oldList);
```

You should know that this creates a *shallow copy* of the original `ArrayList`, so all of the objects in both lists will be the same, but the two lists will be different objects.

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is ambiguous, you can use

`List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>(oldList);` to copy an old **List**

and

`Arrays.copyOf()` to copy array.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.arraycopy()

public static void arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)
```

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

Every Collection Class provide a constructor to crate a duplicate collection Object.

```
List<Movie> newList = new ArrayList<Movie>(oldList);
```

since newList and oldList are different object so you can also create a clone of this object-

```
public static List<Movie> cloneList(List<Movie> oldList) {
    List<Movie> clonedList = new ArrayList<Movie>(oldList.size());
    for (Movie movie: oldList) {
        clonedList.add(new Movie(movie));
    }
    return clonedList;
}
```

ArrayList is also dynamic array,but if you want to store this in array you can do this as-

```
int n=oldList.size();
Movie[] copiedArray=new Movie[n];

for (int i=0;i<oldList.size();i++){
copiedArray[i]=oldList.get(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get Array from original Array List as below:

```
Movie movieArray[] = arrayListMovie
    .toArray(new Movie[arrayListMovie.size()]);
```